# Cannot compile a C++ program in Xcode, but it compiles fine in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c++, xcode, strtok

I am having an issue compelling a program in Xcode but it compiles fine in Visual Studio Express 2013.
This is actually an example that my professor in school typed out and is using to show us how tokens work in C++.  I did not write this.  The errors that I get are on the following lines:

```
 while (tokenptr != '\0')   // while tokenptr is not a null (then must be a token)
    error is: "Comparison between pointer and integer('char' and 'int)"

 tokenptr = strtok('\0', " ,.!?;:");  // get next token from null where left off
    error is: "No matching function for call to 'strtok'"
```

I have the feeling that the issue is with '\0' since the program is highlighting that.
Can anyone please help me to understand the problem?

Thanks

```
/*
Exercise 3-12
 This program will change an English phrase to Pig Latin
 */
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void plw(char []);

int main()
{
    char sent[50], *tokenptr;
    cout << "Enter a sentence:  ";
    cin.getline(sent, sizeof(sent), '\n');  // input up to size of cstring or until enter
    tokenptr = strtok(sent, " ,.!?;:");  // get first token
    while (tokenptr != '\0')   // while tokenptr is not a null (then must be a token)
    {
        plw(tokenptr);   // convert this cstring token to Pig Latin
        cout << " ";   // put space back in (old space was delimiter and removed)
        tokenptr = strtok('\0', " ,.!?;:");  // get next token from null where left off
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// function to take each word token (or cstring or char array) and print as Pig Latin
void plw(char word[])
{
    int x;
    for (x = 1; x < strlen(word); x++)
        cout << word[x];
    cout << word[0] << "ay";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not let you use '\0' in place of a null pointer. Technically, it should let you do it, and quietly cast to `NULL`. However, for readability you should really be passing `NULL` for null pointer, like this:

```
while (tokenptr != NULL)
```

or even skip the check altogether, like this:

```
while (tokenptr)
```

The second way to check for `NULL` is idiomatic to C/C++, but not everyone likes it, preferring to add `!= NULL` anyway.

Similarly, you should pass `NULL` to `strtok`:

```
strtok(NULL, " ,.!?;:")
```

Finally, since `strtok` is not re-entrant, consider using [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Another issue that I am having happens a lot.
Now the program compiles fine but I don't actually get the input box to enter my sentence. What I do get in place of that box is a box with a black background (similar to the input box) with green letters that state (lldb). I believe this has something to do with the debugger. To the left of that is a box that shows my sent array with the tokenptr variable. sent char [50]
tokenptr char * ""

There is a green L to the left of each of them and I can expand each one.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @JustinPosner You should ask a new question for this to get some attention from others who may have experienced the same issue.